# remove from superview

Tags: uiview

am adding one view to another view and when I remove new view then which method of first view will called ?

**here i try viewWillAppear but it doesn't call.**

Can anyone tell me about this?

I add view like,

```
[self.view addSubview:newview.view];
```

and I remove remove this view by ,

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

**can Somebody tell me which method will be call when removeFromSuperview**.

Answer (score 0):

Give `viewDidAppear` a shot. `viewWillAppear` is sketchy at best for certain scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding and removing a subview, viewWillAppear will not get called on the superView or other views in the superview.  You need to use a navigation controller, modal view controller, or tab view controller in order for this to work as you expect.  It seems like you should use a UINavigationController and use push/pop instead of add/remove.